# Does/can Passenger use clusters like Mongrel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, mongrel

I'm just curious if Passenger does or can utilize clusters like Mongrel can. If so, how can I specifically run Passenger with clusters? I'm using nginx. And if not, how does it outperform Mongrel so well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongrel Cluster just runs a specified number of Mongrel processes and assigns incoming HTTP requests to them using Apache's [mod_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) module which acts as a reverse proxy and performs load balancing.

Passenger spawns worker (Ruby) processes to handle HTTP requests using one of [three different and configurable strategies](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#spawning_methods_explained). When Passenger's *smart* spawning method is used it is able to cache the Ruby on Rails framework code, which significantly decreases spawn time. Passenger is also able to re-use the already loaded Ruby interpreter, rather than loading a new one for each process.