# Deploy Rails app to EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

My setup: Rails 2.3.10, Ruby 1.8.7 on Windows

The last time I deployed a Rails app from Windows to Linux on Slicehost, I used Capistrano, Nginx, Mongrel, and SVN. That was 3 years ago, fast forward to now, I'm still on Windows for development and is now looking to deploy to EC2. A quick search turns up tools like Rubber and Chef which aren't easy to grasp with a quick read. It seems like Rubber and Chef are designed for multi-EC2 instances deployment which will be useful when I need to scale.

I'm also new to Passenger but it seems to be the default way to deploy Rails app nowadays, one thing that isn't so clear to me is whether Passenger is a replacement for Mongrel? In my old setup, I configured Nginx to forward the Rails requests to a cluster of Mongrel processes but I don't see anything like that for Passenger.

Any insights are much appreciated.

Comment: If it is not a requirement to deploy to EC2, maybe take a look at heroku.com. Here is a video how to use heroku with windows: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/windows

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am already using Heroku as a staging / testing server. For production, I plan to deploy to EC2, initially on 1 instance but the deployment should scale to multiple instances when needed. I'm thinking that the EC2 instance should pull the latest git source from Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use something like what you're describing for our production server:  EC2 + Apache + Passenger.  We haven't had any need to use the fancy deployment tools you describe - plain old Capistrano (plus [capistrano-ext](https://github.com/jamis/capistrano-ext) so we can use it for multiple environments) does the job just fine.  I've looked at Rubber (not Chef), but deemed it needlessly automagical and too poorly documented, and I'm really not sure what it offers that can't be done just as well with roles in Capistrano.

Passenger has been great.  It's an "overseer" that [manages a collection of Mongrel-like workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004300/does-can-passenger-use-clusters-like-mongrel) (I had thought that the workers were Mongrels, but upon further reading, I don't think they are.  The [Passenger comparisons page](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/comparisons.html#overall_conclusion) even compares its RPS to a Mongrel cluster, so...), starting them up as needed, culling them under low loads, restarting them if they crash, etc.  It's actually very similar to the Server + Mongrel Cluster you described, but probably a bit better, as Passenger has an understanding of the underlying workers that Nginx / Apache don't.  And you'll have to make [a few minor tweaks](http://www.zorched.net/2008/06/17/capistrano-deploy-with-git-and-passenger/) to get Capistrano playing nicely with Passenger.

And if possible, pair Passenger with [Ruby Enterprise Edition](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/) (from the same guys who made Passenger).  It's a much faster version of Ruby, mostly due to a rewritten, configurable garbage collector.  You'll have to [tune your GC settings](http://smartic.us/2010/10/27/tune-your-ruby-enterprise-edition-garbage-collection-settings-to-run-tests-faster/) to get the most out of it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. By capistrano-ext handling multiple environments, do you mean deploying to multiple EC2 instances or something else?

Comment: @Bob  We use capistrano-ext to deploy to different environments.  For example, it lets us deploy to the production server(s) with `cap production deploy` and to the staging server(s) with `cap staging deploy`.  Each environment will have its own "#{environment}.rb" file in config/deploy with any environment-specific Capistrano setup.  This includes a list of all the servers for the environment, so each environment can be deployed to multiple EC2 instances - just list all the instances you want deployed to in the "#{environment}.rb" file.

Answer (score 1):

Both might help:

http://ginzametrics.com/deploy-rails-app-to-ec2-with-rubber.html

[Hosting rails on ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193632/hosting-rails-on-ec2)

Answer (score 0):

[Rubystack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) allows you to have the same Rails environment for development on Windows and for deployment on Linux. We also have EC2 images (scroll to the bottom) and it is completely free, so you may want to give it a try.

Also, this may not work for you, but depending on your requirements, you may want to go for a PaaS solution like [Heroku](http://heroku.com)